# Emoji roles list

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

In my code, I want to show the emojis that can only be used by some specific roles. I tried with this code :

```
emojilist = ''

for e in ctx.guild.emojis:

    emojirolestest = ''

    roles = e.roles

    if roles != []:

        for role in e.roles:

            if role.is_bot_managed() or role.permissions.administrator:

                roles.remove(role)
                
    for r in roles:

        emojiroles[e] = r.mention
                
    emojilist = '{}'.format('\n'.join([f"> {str(e)} `{str(e)}` : {emojiroles[e]}" for e in ctx.guild.emojis if e.roles != []]))
```

But it actually shows only one role. If the emoji has several roles, it will show only one. I want it, obviously, to show all of the roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part yo're aways seting just one role as value:

> ```
> for r in roles:
>      emojiroles[e] = r.mention
> ```

I'm rewriting your code to make it correct and more clean:

```py
emoji_roles = {}

for e in ctx.guild.emojis:
    for role in e.roles:
        if role.is_bot_managed() or role.permissions.administrator:
            continue
        e_roles = emoji_roles.get(e, [])  # geting the list with already addeds roles
        e_roles.append(role)
        emoji_roles[e] = e_roles
text = ''
for e in emoji_roles:
    text += f"{str(e)} `{str(e)}`: {', '.join(r.mention for r in emoji_roles[e])}\n"
```

You don't need to store these values ​​in a dict if you just want to print the `text`:

```py
text = ''
for e in ctx.guild.emojis:
    valid_roles = []
    for role in e.roles:
        if not (role.is_bot_managed() or role.permissions.administrator):
            valid_roles.append(role.mention)
    if valid_roles:
        text += f"{str(e)} `{str(e)}`: {', '.join(valid_roles)}\n"
```

Comment: Thanks ! It is exactly as I wished !